# "ReferenceError: FormData is not defined" on Node.js express server

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

I wrote an express server using Node.js and TypeScript.

The server can receive an array of images and should send them further on to an external API, using a HTTP POST request with form-data instance in the body of the request.

When running locally it works perfectly well, but after deployment to Render hosting service I get this error from the Catch part of the "Try and Catch":

```
Apr 24 05:57:33 PM  Something went wrong, ReferenceError: FormData is not defined
```

I tried to install and import npm's form-data package but then I get a different error when assigning the formData instance into the bodt of the request:

```
Type 'FormData' is not assignable to type 'BodyInit'.
  Type 'FormData' is missing the following properties from type 'URLSearchParams': delete, get, getAll, has, and 7 more.ts(2322)
(property) RequestInit.body?: BodyInit
A BodyInit object or null to set request's body.
```

Does anybody have an idea why is that?

this is the code that runs the HTTP POST request:

```
export class PlanetNetDao extends AbstractDao{
    readonly basicURL: string
    #API_KEY: string
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.basicURL = 'https://my-api.plantnet.org'
        this.#API_KEY = process.env.PLANET_NET_API_KEY
    }
    async fetchIdentifyPlantPost(originalImageNames: string[]) {
        try {
            const formData = new FormData()
        for (let i = 0 ; i < originalImageNames.length ; i++) {
            const imageFile = this.fsReadFileSync(originalImageNames[i])
            const blob = new Blob([imageFile], { type: 'image/jpeg' })
            formData.append('images', blob)
            this.removeImageFromStorage(originalImageNames[i])
        }
        const response = await fetch (`${this.basicURL}/v2/identify/all?include-related-images=true&no-reject=false&lang=en&api-key=${this.#API_KEY}`, 
            {method: 'POST',
            body: formData})
        
        const res = await response.json()
        return res
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong, ' + err)
            throw err
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried to install and import npm's form-data package but then I get a different error" please [edit] your post and put that error in, because installing a package that gives you a `FormData` object is the correct solution, given that Node.js is not a browser, and does not have a FormData object built in.

Comment: thanks for your help. I've added the error which appears on the the POST request 'body' property.

Comment: You said you get errors doing installation, but you're showing a typescript compile-time error, something that Node.js does not do. If you use typescript, remember that you need to tell it where to get its type information from. Right now it's trying to apply the browser's `FormData` type description to "not the browser's `FormData` object".

Comment: 2 things: 1) when I run it locally without installing ```FormData``` Package, it works even when its still an express Node.js server and not a browesr. 2) I'm not sure on how to solve it so I used ```// @ts-ignore```, and then ran it, I get this error: ```TypeError: source.on is not a function```

Comment: You know your version of Node does something, and the remote one doesn't, so... did you check which version of Node is even running remotely?

Comment: in my defense, its my first time deploying :) so I am a bit clueless. my pc runs node.js v18.12.0 while the remote ran v14.somethimg. the interesting thing is that after upgrading the remote to Node.js to v18, it works even without the npm's ```FormData``` package. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: if you have found the solution, please do post an answer here and mark it later on.